# is this a problem in the sp_rename function or sql server itself?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

While renaming the column name, the square bracket is included in the column name, which I think is a bug, 
Here is a sample code snippet,

```
 create table [TestTable]

(TestColumnName nvarchar(30))

select TestColumnName from TestTable

sp_rename '[TestTable].[TestColumnName]', '[RenamedColumnName]', 'Column'

select [RenamedColumnName] from TestTable -- does not work "Invalid column name 'RenamedColumnName'."

select RenamedColumnName from TestTable -- does not work "Invalid column name 'RenamedColumnName'."

select * from [TestTable]  -- works fine!!!
```

The **bug** here is that the column rename **includes the square brackets**, I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874%28SQL.90%29.aspx) which says that the  "first character must be one of the following", but "**[**" does not seem be included in the list, **is there a problem with sp_rename or sql server** itself?, as it allows alteration of column name to start with a square bracket.

Answer (score 5):

The column in your code has been renamed to one that actually includes [] - to query this column you'll have to use

```
SELECT [[RenamedColumnName]]] FROM TestTable
```

] is a delimited identifier, so you have to escape it. For ], this means an additional ] for each one used in the name.

Comment: surprisingly for me, your query works, as it has two sqaure brackets first and 3 at the end,,, :-S

Answer (score 4):

If you want to fix this, you can do this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns where name ='[MyColumn]' AND [object_id]=OBJECT_ID('[MyTable]'))
BEGIN
EXEC sp_rename 'MyTable.[[MyColumn]]]', 'MyColumn', 'COLUMN';
END
```

Don't ask me why it works, it just does.

Answer (score 3):

Data error !!!

Its not

```
sp_rename '[TestTable].[TestColumnName]', '[RenamedColumnName]', 'Column'
```

It should be like this

```
sp_rename '[TestTable].[TestColumnName]', 'RenamedColumnName', 'Column'
```

then

```
select [RenamedColumnName] from TestTable -- works fine!!!

select RenamedColumnName from TestTable -- works fine!!!

select * from [TestTable]  -- works fine!!!
```

Even though the new column name is with space like "Renamed ColumnName" NO NEED TO use the square brackets in the

Comment: I know it is a dataerror from the code end solairaja, but why in the first place does sql server allow the first character to be  NON-identifier in a table or column name? is it a bug?

Comment: see actually, the function sp_rename will not do any validation on the data what ur supplying on the parameter 2. It merely send the data what ur sending to inside the square brackets. so when u supply along with the square brackets its considering tat as the name again. the best proof is the last line in my answer even with space u can send the data.

Comment: It's not a bug - you're allowed to use non-standard field names, so long as you enclose them in square brackets. If you use legal names, you don't need the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug, as "[" and "]" are valid characters within a column name. sp_rename has to work by receiving the exact column name you want to use - after all how would it know whether you wanted a column actually called "[MyColumnWithBrackets]" or "MyColumnWithBrackets". Hence, if you provide a name, it's treated literally and does not require you to manually enclose (e.g.) column names with spaces in, in brackets

Comment: thanks for the reply AdaTheDev, but on the other hand, can you create a table legally by having a square brackets starting the its name?

Comment: You can, by using the same [[]]] syntax as in my response.

Comment: Of course, you really wouldn't want to do this. Using any special characters in object names will probably come back to haunt you.

Comment: Thanks for answering CodeByMoonLight

Comment: Yep, I agree with CodeByMoonlight - I'm personally not a fan of using anything other than alphanumeric and underscore characters in object names. Keep it simple, remove the risk of being bitten.

Comment: definitely, keep it simple, but some strange situations makes them more interesting, isn't it :)

Answer (score 0):

the square brackets are used to mark the boundaries of the columns names. That way you can include reserved words, spaces, single quotes etc. in the column names and the script will not fail.

sp_rename: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238878(SQL.80).aspx

> from BOL: This example renames the
>   contact title column in the customers
>   table to title:   EXEC sp_rename
>   'customers.[contact title]', 'title',
>   'COLUMN'

try this:

```
sp_rename 'TestTable.TestColumnName', 'RenamedColumnName', 'Column'
```

since you are passing in strings into the procedure you don't need  the square braces "[","]"

you can use "[","]" in the first parameter, but if you use them in the second parameter, they become part of the actual column name:

```
create table [TestTable2]([Test ColumnName] nvarchar(30))
exec sp_help testtable2
exec sp_rename 'dbo.TestTable2.[Test ColumnName]', 'Renamed ColumnName', 'Column'
exec sp_help testtable2
```

Comment: It is sort of confusing, then why does this throw an error "select [RenamedColumnName] from TestTable "